# VirtualDocumentRoot in VirtualHost with SSL results in 404 responses

Tags: apache, mod-vhost-alias

I'm trying to configure a very basic server setup where domains are served from their own directory. For example:

- `https://oblik.dev/foo.html` > `/var/www/oblik.dev/foo.html`
- `https://test.oblik.dev/foo.html` > `/var/www/test.oblik.dev/foo.html`
- ...

I've enabled [mod_vhost_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) and I have one VirtualHost in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/main.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/oblik.dev/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/oblik.dev/privkey.pem

    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/$0
    ServerAlias *.dev

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the output of `apache2ctl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  46.101.237.154 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/main.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

And here's the output of `ls -al /var/www/`:

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 Mar 18 06:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Mar 17 06:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 17 09:30 ikarov.oblik.dev
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 18 07:14 oblik.dev
```

I have an `index.php` in both directories with the same permissions as their folders.

When I open `https://oblik.dev`, I get a 404. Same thing for `https://ikarov.oblik.dev`. However, if I substitute `VirtualDocumentRoot` for a regular `DocumentRoot`, the server works as expected.

---

I know that Chrome handles `.dev` domains a bit differently in that [it enforces SSL](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/), but I've set up an SSL certificate with wildcard domains via Let's Encrypt, so it shouldn't be a problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Apache uses `%` for name interpolation instead of `$` like Regex. I had to change this:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/$0
```

...to this:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0
```